# Date sorting data and print only required date columns

Tags: sorting, unix

Suppose I have data like (the file is a text file).

```
Col1  Col2     Col3
user1 21:01:15 user1@gmail.com
user2 22:01:15 user2@gmail.com
user3 19:01:15 user3@gmail.com
user4 16:01:15 user4@gmail.com
```

What I want is to sort and only print columns having time between 19:01:15 to 22:01:15 on the screen. Please help.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I need it via unix command or shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `awk`:

```
$ awk '$2>"19:01:15" && $2<"22:01:15"' file
user1 21:01:15 user1@gmail.com
```

Note that it allows you to write the exact time range you prefer.

In case you want the date range to be "lower or equal than" and "bigger or equal than", do:

```
$ awk ' $2>="19:01:15" && $2<="22:01:15"' file
user1 21:01:15 user1@gmail.com
user2 22:01:15 user2@gmail.com
user3 19:01:15 user3@gmail.com
```